# How do you 'jump' out of a MVC ViewComponent to another controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple scenario where if  a cart is empty, I'd like to  redirect to  another 'page'(controller) which states  the cart is empty or just send them  back  to  the shop.

Heres  my code:

```
   public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        CartFunctions cartf = new CartFunctions(_logger, AppSettings, _httpContextAccessor);
        Cart c = new Cart();
        c = cartf.GetShopingCart();

        if (c.CartItems == null)
        {
          // How do  I get out of  here to  a differnet Controller     
        }


       return View(c.CartItems);

    }
```

If it  was  a controller I could   `return RedirectToAction`
but that is  not available here.

I think the main problem is i need to  either get out OR return  a Cartitems and I can't find  a way to  do  both.

In the good  ole days it was simple with `response.redirect("Empty.aspx")` but now that everything is 'easier' in MVC, it takes days of research to  do  the simplest things.

Comment: Where/How are you calling the view component ? on which event you want to redirect to the specific page ?

Comment: Its  being called   from  a containing page e.g.
 
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Basket")

Answer (score 2):

A view component does not sound like the ideal option do this redirect. View components are ideal for **rendering** some partial views. For example, rendering your cart item count or content, using the view component is a good idea.

In your case, you want to redirect to another action method when the cart is empty. You may create an action filter to do that. You can apply it on action method level or controller level as needed.

```
public class CheckCartValues : ActionFilterAttribute
{       
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {            
        if (yourIfConditionToCheckCartIsEmpty)
        {
            context.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
                                               controller = "Shop", action = "index" }));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

You can apply it on the controller level

```
[CheckCartValues]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Make sure you do not have it on the `ShopController` or you will get infinite redirects. You can also update the action filter code to not do the redirect when the current request is for the `ShopController` if needed. I will leave it up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an attribute you can derive from ActionMethodSelectorAttribute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.isvalidforrequest(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute.IsValidForRequest(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,System.Reflection.MethodInfo).

For example you could create an attribute named CartStatus(bool isEmpty) and apply the attribute to the method(s) that need to behave differently based on cart status.  Then you have your conditional logic in exactly one place (this attribute) and you can reuse it across your application.  Similar to @shyju's approach but instead of redirect you just return true/false from this method for the action that is appropriate.